# Insert data from form into table not working, returns no error

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have created a form with a simple image upload (which i have previously used) and a few fields on. I am trying to get the data from this to insert into my mysql database but this isnt working as hoped. I cannot see anything wrong from my end.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', 1);
require_once('../../includes/connection.inc.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $dir1 = '/xampp/htdocs/manchesterunited/img/teams/';
    $file = $dir1 . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp,$file);
    mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO league-table VALUES ('','".$_POST['team']."', '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','$name')");
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add team</title>
</head>
<body>
<a>Add Team To League</a>
<form action="add-team.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><label for="file">Please select the team's badge: </label><input type="file" name="file"/></p>
    <p><label for="team">Please enter the team:</label><input type="text" name="team"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"/></p>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "<br />Team has been added.";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't return an error because you didn't check for (MySQL) errors in:

```
INSERT INTO league-table
```

MySQL sees that as `league` MINUS `table`

So, wrap it in ticks

```
INSERT INTO `league-table`
```

Or rename the table name using an underscore.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Adding `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` to `mysqli_query()` would have thrown you something about it.

You're also open to an SQL injection. Use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

However, this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "<br />Team has been added.";
}
```

You're better off using a conditional statement for your query instead.

Plus, you have the same conditional statement twice.

*In a nutshell:*

- if(query) successful, echo success.
- else, do error handling.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time lol. Silly error on my part, should've realised :) I'll mark it as answered in 10 mins when I can. Thank you :)